# Parallel step execution of ItemStreamReader in SpringBatch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a `ItemStreamReader` (`extends AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`), the reader on its own is quite fast, but the the following processing takes quite some time.
From a business point of view I can process as many items in parallel as I want.

As my `ItemStreamReader` is reading a large JSON file with a JsonParser, it ends up to be statefull. So just adding a `TaskExecutor` to the `Step` does not work and throws parsing exceptions and the following log output by spring batch:

```
16:51:41.023 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.s.b.FaultTolerantStepBuilder - Asynchronous TaskExecutor detected with ItemStream reader.  This is probably an error, and may lead to incorrect restart data being stored.
16:52:29.790 [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-1] WARN  o.s.b.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor - No ItemReader set (must be concurrent step), so ignoring offset data.
16:52:31.908 [feed-import-1] WARN  o.s.b.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor - ItemStream was opened in a different thread.  Restart data could be compromised.
```

How can I execute the processing in my Step to be executed in parallel by multiple threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Batch provides a number of ways to parallelize processing.  In your case, since processing seems to be the bottle neck, I'd recommend looking at two options:

**AsyncItemProcessor/AsyncItemWriter**
The `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter` work in tandem to parallelize the processing of items within a chunk.  You can think of them as a kind of fork/join concept.  The items within the chunk are read by a single thread as normal.  The `AsyncItemProcessor` wraps your normal `ItemProcessor` and executes that logic on a different thread, returning a `Future` instead of the actual item.  The `AsyncItemWriter` then waits for the `Future` to return the processed item before writing it.  These classes are found in the Spring Batch Integration module.  You can read more about them in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#asynchronous-processors

**Remote Chunking**
The `AsyncItemProcessor`/`AsyncItemWriter` paradigm works well in a single JVM, but if you need to scale your processing further, you may want to take a look at remote chunking.  Remote chunking is designed to scale the processor piece of a step to beyond a single JVM.  Using a master/slave configuration, the master reads the input using a regular `ItemReader`.  Then the items are sent via Spring Integration channels to the slaves for processing.  The results can either be written in the slave or returned to the master for writing.  It's important to note that in this approach, each item read by the master will go over the wire so it can be very IO intensive and should only be considered if the processing bottle neck is worse than the potential impact of sending the messages.  You can read more about remote chunking in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#externalizing-batch-process-execution

Comment: thanks Michael, that's great! but I think there is an issue with the 'AsyncItemProcessor' together with a 'CompositeItemProcessor'. The chunk passed to the 'ItemWriter' always has the size of the original chunk size, regardless if some of the items got filtered. In other words: the 'List' passed to the 'ItemWriter' contains 'null' entries. So the number of writes reported by spring batch will most probably not be correct.

Comment: Good observation.  We fixed the issue with the potential NPEs in https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2297.  However there is an open issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2325 for fixing the write counts.  Since the counts are purely for accounting reasons (they serve no purpose from a processing standpoint), you could still use the functionality...

Comment: from looking at the issue, it should be resolved with 3.0.2, but thats the version i'm using and still seeing the issue. An other problem I'm facing is that can't use 'ItemProcessListener' in the same way anymore, right? 'ItemProcessListener.afterProcess' will throw a 'ClasscastException' because of the 'Future' - I kind of understand this, but it makes the configuration with JavaConfig a bit hard (incompatibility between the Reader/Writer/Listeners).

Comment: What is the exact issue you're seeing with 3.0.2?  The counts will be off.  That issue has not been fixed.  What was fixed was that `ItemWriter` implementations typically don't check for nulls, so when the `AsyncItemWriter` passed a null to the delegate, a NPE would occur.  The `AsyncItemWriter` now filters out the nulls.  For the `ItemProcessListener` issue, I'd have to see your configuration.

Comment: yep, the issue I'm still seeing is that `AsyncItemWriter` is still getting null values. But I'm using Spring Batch Integration 1.3.1

Comment: `AsyncItemWriter` will receive nulls.  There's nothing we can do to prevent that.  However, the delegate `ItemWriter` should not receive the nulls.

Comment: Oh sorry, Its my own `ItemWriter` used as delegate in the `AsyncItemWriter` which gets nulls (in Spring Batch Integration 1.3.1). Looking at the sources (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemWriter.java#L54-L56), this seems to be fixed but not released (as of 3.0.3)

Comment: domi, since that's a behavior change to existing functionality, I'm holding it back until the 3.1.0 release.

Comment: I don't see how option 1 addresses the Reader, then I could use a specific example of option 2.