# Spring Batch "Asynchronous TaskExecutor detected with ItemStream reader"

Tags: spring-batch

First of all, this question seems to be nearly exactly what we're wanting to do:
[Parallel step execution of ItemStreamReader in SpringBatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803478/parallel-step-execution-of-itemstreamreader-in-springbatch)

Spring batch 3.0.10, running under a Java EE server (WebSphere, Java 8, Java EE 6). I'm also not the original author of this code.

XML configuration, we have a batch step with a read of a line from a file, process the line (the part we want to multi-thread) and a write of a record to a database:

```xml
    <batch:step id="processRenewalsStep" next="saveResponseFileStep">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="4">
            <batch:chunk
                reader="batchRenewalCsvFileItemReader"
                writer="asyncBatchRenewalDb2ItemWriter"
                processor="asyncBatchRenewalProcessor"
                commit-interval="1"
                skip-limit="10">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="batchSkipListener"/>
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Even after following [the suggested aynchronous wrapping in the accepted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27808167/796761):

```xml
<bean id="asyncBatchRenewalProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor"
      p:taskExecutor-ref="taskExecutor"
      p:delegate-ref="batchRenewalProcessor"/>

<bean id="asyncBatchRenewalDb2ItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter"
      p:delegate-ref="batchRenewalDb2ItemWriter"/>
```

Our startup log still contains:

> 22:25:25,252 (Default : 3) WARN org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.FaultTolerantStepBuilder:Asynchronous TaskExecutor detected with ItemStream reader. This is probably an error, and may lead to incorrect restart data being stored.

And

> 22:34:03,755 (WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 0) WARN org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor:No ItemReader set (must be concurrent step), so ignoring offset data.

And several instances of:

> 22:34:03,880 (WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 2) WARN org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor:ItemStream was opened in a different thread.  Restart data could be compromised.

Which I suppose makes some sense, because we wrapped the Processor and Writer, but there is no class to wrap the Reader?

Running my job, logging does indicate that different threads from my container Executor are being used, but I didn't try this before using the Asynchronous wrappers, so maybe it would have "worked" even without that?

So is there any way to prevent the WARNings, and the condition they're warning about?

**Update**: Based on [this in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep):

> If a reader is not thread safe, it may still be efficient to use it in your own synchronizing delegator. You can synchronize the call to read() and as long as the processing and writing is the most expensive part of the chunk your step may still complete much faster than in a single threaded configuration.

I've tried creating a `FlatFileItemReader` subclass that does synchronize its own `read()` method, that calls the underlying `read()` method, but I'm still getting the WARN logging. I don't know if I misunderstood that advice or if what I did now is safe but can't be detected as safe, so it's still logging.

Answer (score 3):

The `FlatFileItemReader` is not thread safe as it extends `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` which is [not thread-safe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html). So using it in a multi-threaded step is not correct (otherwise execution context data might corrupted by concurrent threads, hence the warnings).

To avoid any concurrency issue, you can try partitioning the file (either physically or logically) and make each thread work on a different partition.

Comment: Thanks, any details on how to do the latter? And is there then not any thread-safe file reader?

Comment: What about my synchronized `FlatFileReader` subclass? Sorry, I'm just stuck trying to envision any concrete solution to this problem.

Comment: The wrapper for item reader you are looking for is `SynchronizedItemStreamReader` (this would replace your custom reader that synchronizes the `read` method). But that will not fix the warnings. The issue here is about state management in a multi-threaded step. This state is used in a restart scenario. If you don't care about restartability, you can turn off the state (set `saveState(false)` on the reader) and safely ignore those warnings.

Comment: The partitioning technique I mentioned is illustrated here: https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/issues/so53366710. I use the `split` command to physically split the input file. This approach is not portable, you can replace it with an equivalent java code.